# Windows 7 Window focus issue

Tags: windows-7, window-focus, always-on-top

This problem has been making me crazy - I can't seem to figure out the cause of it. When I have overlapping windows, if I click on the window "behind" the one that currently has focus, it doesn't always come to the front. It doesn't occur with the same application either.

Sometimes it'll happen when I have Explorer open. Or Xplorer2, or Visual Studio. Or Chrome. In development it's really frustrating because I can open a modal Window which suddenly appears *behind* the dev. environment and now appears to be hung because I can't actually get to that window.

Sometimes if I close a bunch of windows it suddenly goes away. I thought it was originally Chrome causing the problem since normally when I completely closed it, the focus problem would go away. But that hasn't proven itself out as time has gone on. It appears as if one (random) application suddenly gets stuck with an "Always on Top"-type setting, so if it isn't minimized I have these issues. If I close that app. it suddenly starts working for a while.
/*
This is on a Dell M6700 laptop running Windows 7. I thought it may be one of the apps that comes preloaded on this machine (Dell Smart Settings, some color manager), so I closed them down. I also attempted to upgrade to the latest set of drivers (ATI FirePro M6000 video), but the problem hasn't gone away.

I ran AutoRuns and went through the list but I didn't see anything that seemed weird (of course, I could have missed something). I have another laptop (HP) that has a similar set of apps installed that doesn't have this problem.

Anyone run into this before?

**EDIT:** Sounds like the same issue as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/269415/show-desktop-sometimes-sets-a-window-to-always-on-top).

Comment: Windows 8.1 user here. I am [also experiencing this issue](http://superuser.com/questions/877533/windows-are-acting-as-if-they-are-always-on-top).